# Toggle Kendo Splitter on button click inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, iframe, kendo-splitter

my Kendo Splitter is as below.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Splitter()
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:590px;", id = "mainSplitter" })
      .Orientation(SplitterOrientation.Horizontal)
      .Panes(horizontalPanes =>
      {
          horizontalPanes.Add()
              .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "left-pane" })
              .Size("246px")
              .Collapsible(true)
              .Content(@<text></text>);
          horizontalPanes.Add()
              .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "right-pane", style = "overflow:hidden;" })
            .Content(@<iframe id="tabsContent_iframe" src='' data-src='' style="width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>
            );
      })
)
```

In my POC, I had a button outside the splitter used to toggle the `left-pane` which worked perfectly.

Now, if I used the same button inside my iframe and make the call. It doesn't work.

I tried doing it in couple of ways as below:

1)

```
 var parentSplitterId = parent.$('#mainSplitter').data("kendoSplitter");
  var parentLeftTogglePane = parent.$('#full-pane');// , window.parent.document);
    parentSplitterId[parentLeftTogglePane.width() > 0 ? "collaspe" : "expand"](parentLeftTogglePane);
```

2)

```
 var parentSplitterId = window.parent.document.getElementById('mainSplitter');
var parentLeftTogglePane = $('#full-pane', window.parent.document);
var splitter = $("#parentSplitterId").data("kendoSplitter");
splitter[leftTogglePane.width() > 0 ? "collaspe" : "expand"](leftTooglePane);
```

I am not able to understand where I am going wrong or what I'm missing. Please guide me out here.

Thanks

Comment: In the code you tried, does the `parentSplitterId` variable get its value?

Comment: Yeah. I'm able to get the instance of the `parentSplitterId`. But the last line is where I'm getting this error:

`parentSplitterId[(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)] is not a function`

Comment: You have mispelled `collapse`, could it be it?

Comment: Wow! Thanks a ton . Can't believe I was working on this for days :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple as you misspelled the word `collapse`, you wrote `collaspe` instead.